# How to display two detail grids inside a master grid (not nested)

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, master-detail

AG Grid has an example on how to render nested Detail Grids as shown in the picture below.

[image: Nested Detail Grids]

What I need however, is to display two detail grids on top of one another.

Comment: whats your mean detail grid ?

Comment: I have attached one image above, so A1 is master grid and A2 is detail grid.

Comment: sry men. i havent any answer for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It looks as though you're trying to get someone to write code for you which is not what this website is for _ Please add any code attempt that you've tried. You should also visit SO Help Center 'Asking' section to find out more about submitting a properly formatted question _ Doing this will help to ensure that your post isn't down-voted >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

To display two grids that are not nested, you will need to follow the Custom Detail Cell Renderer (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/master-detail-custom-detail/#example-custom-detail-with-grid) example and adapt it to display two grids.

Template Code:

```
DetailCellRenderer.prototype.getTemplate = function () {
  var data = this.params.data;
  var template = `<div class="full-width-panel">
    <div class="full-width-grid1 ag-theme-alpine"></div>
    <div class="full-width-grid2 ag-theme-alpine"></div>
    </div>`;

  return template;
};
```

Detail Setup

```
DetailCellRenderer.prototype.setupDetailGrid = {
  new agGrid.Grid(eDetailGrid1, detailGridOptions1);
  new agGrid.Grid(eDetailGrid2, detailGridOptions2);

  this.detailGridApi1 = detailGridOptions1.api;
  this.detailGridApi2 = detailGridOptions2.api;

  var masterGridApi = this.params.api;
  var rowId = this.params.node.id;

  const gridInfo1 = {
    id: rowId,
    api: detailGridOptions1.api,
    columnApi: detailGridOptions1.columnApi,
  };

  const gridInfo2 = {
    id: rowId,
    api: detailGridOptions2.api,
    columnApi: detailGridOptions2.columnApi,
  };

  masterGridApi.addDetailGridInfo(`${rowId}_1`, gridInfo1);
  masterGridApi.addDetailGridInfo(`${rowId}_2`, gridInfo2);
}
```

Detail Destruction

```
DetailCellRenderer.prototype.destroy = function () {
  const rowId = this.params.node.id;
  const masterGridApi = this.params.api;

  masterGridApi.removeDetailGridInfo(`${rowId}_1`);
  masterGridApi.removeDetailGridInfo(`${rowId}_2`);

  this.detailGridApi1.destroy();
  this.detailGridApi2.destroy();
};
```

Here is a working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Bj0Uf6fvTh1PEBw1

Comment: In the attached screenshot A2 is inside A1 and A3 is inside A2, But in my case A2 and A3 should be one below another inside A1

Comment: Well, you should have said that. I’ll try and adjust the example later

Comment: i changed the answer to show how to add two grids that are not nested.